# cocoa - how to make a non-sandbox macOS app start at login?

Tags: macos, cocoa, launchd, launch-agent

I am developing a non-sandbox macOS app which is not going to be released in App Store, and I want to make the app to run when user log in.

The current method I have found is to use Service Management framework and a helper app, which needs to sign this app. The former valid way was LSSharedFileList, but this method doesn't work in macOS 10.14.

Is there a way I can make this simple app start at login?

Comment: I have code that uses `LSSharedFileList` to set the launch at login; I just tested it and it works well on my Mojave 10.14.4 system

Comment: I was struggling with this for a couple days before I found [this package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin) that solves it gracefully for both Sandboxed and non-Sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register any app with `launched` to run as a user agent.

In this example, an app named On Startup will be launched whenever the user logs in.

Step 1

You'll need to create a "launchd.plist" file to describe the service. In this example, you create a file named `com.yourdomain.onstartup.plist` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.yourdomain.onstartup</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>Aqua</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/On Startup.app/Contents/MacOS/On Startup</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The key point is the `RunAtLoad` property that tells launchd to start the process when the user session loads.

(Note: you can create this file by building a dictionary and writing it as a property list.)

Step 2:

Install that file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. This is where launchd looks for per-user launchd configuration files.

Step 3:

Execute the command

```
launchctl bootstrap ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourdomain.onstartup.plist
```

or simply wait until the system restarts.

The `bootstrap` command tells launchd that a new service wants to be registered and activated immediately, but all of the files in `LaunchAgents` will get registered automatically the next time the user logs in.

If you need your app to run all the time, consider adding a `KeepAlive` property. And there are about a billion other options.

Step 4:

To stop your app from starting again at login, delete the `com.yourdomain.onstartup.plist` file.

If you've set the `KeepAlive` property, you'll also want to invoke `launchctl bootout gui/501/com.yourdomain.onstartup` command to stop the service and unregister it immediately. (Note: this will kill your app.)

See

`man launchd.plist`

`man launchctl`

[macOS Daemons and Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html)